# Can anyone explain how this circuit works?

Tags: ac

This is from an electric portable stove.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/xo7rs.jpg]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a very simple thermostat. One of those pieces of metal is actually bimetallic. The dial controls the distance between the top piece of metal (call it a "setting level") and its stop. The bimetallic element will actually curl away from the top piece as it heats up. If the dial is turned to a low setting (far away from the bimetallic element) then the bimetallic element just has to curl a little to "get away" from the setting level, thus breaking the circuit and stopping the heating. If the dial is set up high, then the bimetallic metal has to curl a fair amount to get away and break the connection.

As the bimetallic element cools, it straightens back out and will eventually make contact again, starting the heating process over.

Those little round discs are the contacts. Sometimes they are mildly magnetic in order to help "make" a good solid contact to start the heating process.

Comment: I'm a little confused about each of the parts you're describing. The two disc's separate whenever the knob is turned. The white part in the middle seems to have a little metal piece on the end of it.

Comment: Does the knob need to be near the heat source?

Comment: After taking a lighter to this I understand better how it works.  I'm curious how it controls current flow though. I imagine those contacts are involved. Does it work similar to a capacitor?

Comment: It doesn't control current flow in any variable sense. As the strips heat up, they pull away from each other due to the bimetallic strip. When the two contacts on the left of the picture separate, the heating element turns off. The oven slowly cools, which pushes the contacts back together, turning the element back on. Turning the dial essentially alters how hot the strips need to get before the contacts separate.